# Using dayjs with Sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper, dayjs

I have been using `moment.js` in a page in my Sapper app. When I build the project, I noticed that `moment.js` takes up quite some space, so I tried to switch over to [dayjs](https://day.js.org) instead.

However, whenever I try to open the page in which I am using `day.js`, the page simply fails and says that it is taking a long time to respond. Any ideas why this is happening?

**Steps to reproduce**

- get the Sapper project
- npm install dayjs
- use it in any page, and observe the behavior

**Info**

- Day.js Version: 1.8.34
- OS: Linux Mint 19.3 (Cinnamon 4.4.8)
- Browser: Chrome 80.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test it and it's working fine if you import it as a module:

```html
<script>
  import dayjs from "dayjs";

  console.log(dayjs("2018-08-08"));
</script>
```

You will see in the console something like:

```js
{
  $L: "en"
  $d: Wed Aug 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
  $y: 2018
  $M: 7
  ...
}
```

Checkout the [sapper codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-meadow-6xetj?file=/src/routes/index.svelte) and the [classic svelte codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-lake-rdn7x?file=/App.svelte:0-124) to see it live.

Comment: How do you load plugins for `dayjs` as required for the `dayjs().week()` method (which requires loading the `weekOfYear` plugin [ref](https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/week))?

Comment: @Thismatters I have the code for that but doesn't fit as a comment. Could you please open a new question and post the link of it here? I will share you the code there.